# how to save data in the background every 2 minutes in Laravel

Tags: laravel, background

we're making a web app that's supposed to save the patient's viral signs history in the database, like every two minutes or so in the background. is it possible to do that in laravel if so how can i do it?

Comment: You can use the [task scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling) if you are able to add new cronjobs on your system.

Comment: Will you be saving data from client side? Or you mean to auto generate some kind of report server side?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using job:

php artisan make:job PatientViralSignsJob

this command will generate class PatientViralSignsJob in app\Jobs folder.

in the PatientViralSignsJob ... hande() method you could write your logic

```
public function handle()
{
   // write your code here ...
}
```

finally register your job class in Console\Kernel.php in schedule method:

```
  protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
         $schedule->job(new PatientViralSignsJob())->everyFiveMinutes();
    }
```

this will make your handle method in PatientViralSignsJob executed every five minutes

more details in:

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#creating-jobs